# Double booked - User bookmarking question recorded twice

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, bookmarks, duplication

In this [user's profile (bookmarks)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/801165/global05?tab=bookmarks&sort=added) one user is shown as having bookmarked [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354069/282094) twice:

[image: User Profile - Bookmarks]

This doesn't appear to be the same question as: [Was there a brief system glitch which caused some questions to be posted twice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354028/282094) **or** [New question asking form sometimes leads to accidental double posts of questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346338/282094) though it's certainly possible that the cause is the same.

Comment: This is a [long-standing issue regarding merges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295693/2-downvotes-on-the-same-question). We don't detect and invalidate duplicate votes when accounts are merged together.

Comment: I was going to edit in [animuson's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354079/double-booked-user-bookmarking-question-recorded-twice#comment1183441_354079) but in the interim it was tagged [status-review by Adam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/354079/3) so I'll leave *that* as the final edit.

Comment: [11 instances on MSE](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1293400) until last sunday

Comment: @adamlear [2478 instances](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1293400#resultSets) on Stack Overflow, using [rene's SEDE query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354079/double-booked-user-bookmarking-question-recorded-twice?noredirect=1#comment1183448_354079) -  this is a fairly large problem if it applies to votes; as [animuson's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354079/double-booked-user-bookmarking-question-recorded-twice?noredirect=1#comment1183441_354079) mentions.

Comment: [This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1067051/naeem-ul-wahhab?tab=bookmarks&sort=added&page=5) has an unusually large number of duplications from page 5 to 11. --- Also, I asked in The Tavern chat if rene's SEDE query is undercounting.

Comment: Another [interesting anomaly](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8881587#8881587) is that a user can be shown simultaneously that they have both voted up and down for the same question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for raising this. I've reproduced this and confirmed with the SEDE work you've all done (thank you!) that this is still an issue. I've put this onto our backlog to address, but it may take some time before we get to it based on where our roadmap priorities are. Adding [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) for now, and will have the team update here once we get at this again.

Answer (score 7):

Ultimately we might want to handle duplicate votes of all types, but those have a higher potential for edge cases (for example, how far would we want to or need to go to reverse any effects that those votes had - deleted posts, post owner's reputation, etc), so for now, we're going with the two simplest cases - bookmarks and follows.

Future user merges will take care of duplicate bookmarks and follows by soft-deleting the ones coming in from the merged user, and I've also removed the duplicate bookmark for this specific user.

Thanks for the report!

Comment: So only those bookmarks that both the parent user and merged user had placed will be removed, or will all bookmarks be removed from the merged user on merging (including non-duplicates)?

Comment: The mentioned user has only one bookmark, but the question has two bookmarks and it shows only one on [its history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/354069/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries). Should I blame caching?

Comment: Thanks Adam. BTW [voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354079/double-booked-user-bookmarking-question-recorded-twice/370888#comment1183475_354079) is an issue, and very difficult to correct, in The Tavern almost 2 months ago a user reported that the arrows indicated that they had both voted up and down; I don't recall who (Forest?) reporting it to Catija?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Only duplicates. Everything else will be moved over to the parent user. (Technically, even duplicate bookmark/follow votes are moved over, but they'll have a deletion date set.)

Comment: @RafaelTavares Yeah, the bookmark count is stored separately on the post, but it should update overnight.

Comment: @Rob Hah. Looks like forest's situation has already been handled. I believe users in that situation should be able to self-correct it if they are able to retract whichever vote they don't want to keep (though it might require a post edit).