# Duplicated votes are being cleaned up

Tags: discussion, voting, announcements, duplication

It was [reported on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418080/i-upvoted-a-post-twice-actually-10-times) that it is possible for a user to upvote or downvote more than once on a single post (resulting in reputation changes for the author for each vote).

After some data examination, we were able to confirm that this vulnerability exists (it is happening due to [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) surrounding vote submission), and has been in the system since literally the first day that the site went live.

While there is some evidence that a few users have knowingly abused this, the spread of votes suggests that in nearly every instance, users submitted duplicate votes by accident.

Duplicated votes exist on every site in the network. Here are the sites that had the highest numbers of duplicate votes before invalidation (after that, the numbers quickly went down to fewer than 100 per site):

1. Stack Overflow: ~13K
2. Mathematics: ~3K
3. Stack Overflow in Russian: ~1K
4. Biblical Hermeneutics: ~950
5. Stack Overflow in Portuguese: ~940
6. MathOverflow: ~550
7. English Language and Usage: ~450
8. Cross Validated: ~430
9. Physics: ~300
10. English Language Learners: ~220

Because of the nature of the race condition, the relative infrequency of occurrences, and the potential negative ramifications for performance that could happen if we were to fully eliminate the race condition, we are not going to be changing the way in which votes are recorded on the site. Instead, we have **completed** a one-time cleanup for **all** duplicate votes in the database, and a daily cleanup for the small number of duplicate votes that are registered each day **has been enabled**.

Even with the daily cleanup in place, we will consider intentional usage of this bug to be misuse of Stack Exchange systems. We will be monitoring this, and will consider these to be in the same league as other types of voting fraud, so anyone who was thinking about experimenting with this, please consider yourself forewarned.

If you have any questions or comments, please post them as answers below, and we'll be happy to answer them.

Comment: Will this also correct the extra down vote caused by spam flags? I always assumed that was deliberate. (I *think* is caused by spam flags; it's also likely spammy posts just collect down votes very quickly and it's co-incidence.)

Comment: Is the current use of the community user as recipient for votes from deleted users the only thing that would prevent handling this at the DB level? My naive view would be that otherwise votes could be declared unique in the DB per (user, post, type) combination.

Comment: @MadScientist Close/reopen votes and bounties are stored in the same table as normal up/down votes (at least in SEDE), so for those it is possible for there to be multiple votes from the same users.

Comment: @Smitop that's why I added "type" there, as long as only active bounties are in there the combination of user, post and vote type should still be unique

Comment: @MadScientist It's possible for a user to place multiple close or reopen votes on a question. Those votes age away after a time (time varies, depending on the number of views and existence of other such votes by other users). 14 days after the vote ages away, the user is allowed to place another, potentially identical, vote. This can be repeated any number of times. So, no, that's not sufficient to make them unique.

Comment: @BSMP Downvotes resulting from spam flags should not be affected by this change.

Comment: It's great to clean up the duplicate voting from this bug.  +2, I mean, +1.

Comment: I've seen many reports of this here. In all those cases, it was because [two accounts had voted on the same post and were later merged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295724/377214).

Comment: @SonictheSaveUkraine-hog Yeah, that does sometimes result in duplicate votes appearing on the same post from the same post-merge account. Those votes will also be removed by this cleanup.

Comment: Reminds me of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dc5lK.png): instead of fixing the roof, place a bucket to collect the water. This is still much better than having the water ruin the house. :)

Comment: Unintented clickbait title mentioning "duplicate votes"... but I guess it worked because I'm here ;) Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: @Makyen Filtered unique indexes exist though e.g. `UNIQUE INDEX u ON dbo.Votes (PostId, UserId, VoteTypeId) WHERE VoteTypeId IN (1, 2) AND UserId > 0;`

Comment: Fixing a race condition with a cleanup task is not a solution, but a mere workaround. The time spent on monitoring this could have been used to redesign the procedure. And even when recording duplicate votes, this doesn't necessarily mean to count duplicate votes.

Comment: @MartinZeitler everything has its tradeoffs. Preventing this from ever happening would require a good deal more work than what we ended up doing (especially since the issue is triggered in a number of different ways). And the issue happens infrequently enough that adding additional queries after every vote, or locking posts completely while processing a vote in order to prevent duplicate votes (frequency: approximately 1:20K votes) is adding on a good deal of additional processing to a very common action where the benefit is barely felt (but the impact of the additional queries can be felt).

Comment: @YaakovEllis It's understandable that site complexity and vast amounts of content do not make the task of fundamental redesign any easier... during the last outage I've noticed that the voting button kept attaching loading spinners to the GUI when the backend was disconnected.

Comment: @Luuklag curious about your edit, what gave you the impression the cleanup is completed? Also, it will never be completed, it's clearly said there's going to be "a daily cleanup for the small number of duplicate votes that are registered each day" and this announcement is about this as well, not only the one time cleanup. (Which I'm also not sure whether it's completed or not.)

Comment: @MartinZeitler if you mean [such thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90254/loading-indicator-is-reproducing), just with voting? Also, about "workaround, not a solution" you are right, however I do agree with that approach, in this very specific case. If you want to discuss it, feel free to hit me up on chat, I'm in two rooms on this domain.

Comment: @MartinZeitler: If it were my system I would insist on an atomic solution, but I don't have a problem with stackexchange deciding that a daily cleanup is good enough.

Comment: That's also be great to clean [serial downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355329/178179).

Comment: I wonder what's the performance impact of adding a constraint in a DB, it would be easy, high performant, low effort, and you'd cover all the similar cases (see merged users)

Comment: We have many legitimate cases that would violate a constraint. To avoid these cases would require re-engineering a number of unrelated voting scenarios, and would force us to clean up data that we want to keep. It is not an option.

Comment: Currently it is possible to vote on a post on one site and then if it is migrated (with votes preserved) then vote again on it on the target site. Will this sort of duplicated vote also be affected?

Comment: @MartinSmith that type of thing will be cleaned up by the daily job

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it was done last week. Was edited in then, and I just updated it to try to make this more clear.

Comment: Does this mean that users can potentially lose a lot of reputation?

Comment: Does this happen because someone has two tabs open and votes at the same time.  Or is it because someone has done a double-click.  If the latter, then it needs to be fixed.  Just saying :-)  Just tested it, it's double click !!!  And once it has happened on that post, if I downvote (single click) it does two, if I upvote (single click) it still does two. , a single click still acts like a double click - maybe something in the session.

Comment: "*While there is some evidence that a few users have knowingly abused this*" Are those users getting a pass or are they getting suspensions for their Summer Christmas?

Comment: @Enderman only if they're knowingly abusing it. Otherwise, it's rather a rare occurrence to happen naturally.

Comment: Wait, does this mean all those who commented _"Ah, I wish I could upvote you more than once..."_ actually **could** upvote me more than once but didn't? Liars! Liars, I tell you!

Comment: I would have thought the model was `User 1-* Vote *-1 Post` with a unique constraint on `Vote ( UserID, PostID )`, but I guess maybe that would be too slow.

Comment: @DaveCousineau the `Posts2Votes` table contains votes of multiple types, and for almost all of them invalidation is handled as a soft-delete. So constraints just wont work in this situation (not even addressing performance implications).

Comment: Is this 13k duplicate votes in the entire history of stack exchange?

Comment: @MikeKulls yes, 13K duplicate votes on Stack Overflow since the first day of the site in 2008.

Answer (score 85):

> so anyone who was thinking about experimenting with this, please consider yourself forewarned.

I don't intend to use this maliciously, but I do have a habit of pressing buttons twice (or more) when they don't succeed before the system registers it. How will you distinguish abuse from mindless fortuitous clicking?

Comment: I suspect other than rep loss, there won't be a penalty for this?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I'm asking about the voters not the users receiving the vote.

Comment: My mouse does this by itself, just saying. Prefer not to be penalised, but will take my lumps for buying something that glows rainbow colours rather than being technically efficient.

Comment: Looking at the actual data, there is a small number of users that stand out very blatantly as likely having abused this (target of many many votes). These are distinguishable from users where it accidentally happens every so often. If you are in the second group, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @YaakovEllis so you're looking at *recipients* of the votes to determine abuse? That seems safer.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage both recipients and casters, we'd look at both :)

Comment: @YaakovEllis just now, I upvoted Jiminy and your comment once, and it registered as two upvote each. Is this duplicate vote really rare?

Comment: @Vylix: Unlike upvotes on questions and answers, comment upvotes do not get updated in real time. So someone likely upvoted the comments *while* you had this page open. So after *you* upvoted the comments, the number of upvotes on the respective comments was updated.

Comment: @YaakovEllis In terms of casters, I think poor network connection might be a distinct possibility, entirely benign due to POST requests being received by the server but the response not arriving back. So the caster just tries again.

Comment: I did that on your post and nothing happened:) seems i cant reproduce the bug.

Answer (score 30):

There's no difference in the achievement inbox and the profile page between 'regular' serial voting reversals and duplicate voting reversals, or I assume so?

[image]

---

[image]

Then it's probably worth mentioning this as a special case in the [Help Center page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed), which starts with "When a single user continually votes (up or down) on many of your posts within a short period of time". Another case to consider would be [invalidation of 'random' votes cast by badge hunters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362020/295232).

Comment: Correct, it will show up with the same "voting corrected" label as serial voting invalidations.

Comment: I've made an internal note to update the Help Center page.

Comment: Thanks @Slate. Here is some inspiration: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/379864/295232

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks, very helpful. I've pushed an edit through network-wide (translations pending).

Comment: "duplicate voting reversals" What is that?

Answer (score 24):

I had seen a prior report about duplicate votes, but in those cases, it was not due to a race condition, but rather because [two profiles had voted on the same post and were later merged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295724/377214).

Two questions here:

1. The same issue here (with account mergers) also formerly affected bookmarks and follows, as mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/370888/377214). While that issue was fixed for future mergers (bookmarks and follows coming from the source account would be deleted), will this task fix it for the previous cases?
2. One thing I've seen anecdotal reports of is users who upvoted the same post from one profile and downvoted it from another profile, which was later merged into the first. In that case, the system would show both the up and down arrows glowing on the same post. Will this task fix those cases as well?

Comment: I'm answering this by reading unmerged code, so take this with a grain of salt. My understanding is that (1) will not be fixed by this change, and (2) will always preserve the vote with the lowest integer ID. (Since it's a race condition, I don't know if there's a good way to predict whether the upvote or downvote will be preserved.)

Comment: I can confirm the veracity of what Slate wrote. This fix is not addressing either of the other two issues listed here.

Answer (score 8):

Although it will likely be small, this will still affect some users who will lose reputation during the cleanup. How will the system communicate the change to those users? Will it be reported in the reputation section of their profiles? How will it be labelled there? Will the label contain a link to this explanation?

Comment: probably the message will be: "voting corrected"

Comment: @Luuklag true, but since this one here is much more rare, there's chance there won't be any notification or message.

Comment: It will show up with the "voting corrected" label (see Glorfindel's answer for a screenshot). There will not be a link to this explanation.

Comment: I got a voting corrected message a couple of days ago and 10 points taken away.

Comment: @Dexygen yeah, same here. Looks like Yaakov was telling the truth. :-)

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/379854/213957

Answer (score 5):

In the bug report "[Double booked - User bookmarking question recorded twice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354079/282094)" (asked Sep 11, 2020 at 3:53) this double voting was reported and confirmed for Bookmarks, and acknowledged for all types of voting:

> "Ultimately we might want to handle duplicate votes of all types, but those have a higher potential for edge cases (for example, how far would we want to or need to go to reverse any effects that those votes had - deleted posts, post owner's reputation, etc), so for now, we're going with the two simplest cases - bookmarks and follows.
>
> Future user merges will take care of duplicate bookmarks and follows by soft-deleting the ones coming in from the merged user, and I've also removed the duplicate bookmark for this specific user.
>
> Thanks for the report!
>
> answered [Oct 15, 2021 at 20:06](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/370888/282094) - Adam Lear"

Answer (score -3):

I don't understand what is the point in "punishment" if there's nothing left to exploit after you've added a daily cleanup?

Why even bother with monitoring anything, "punishing" people and then dealing with inevitable false positives if there's nothing to exploit now?

If there are technical solution to the problem, drop all "political" ones. As long as technical is 100% working, it is always better.

Comment: The bug allowing more than one vote by same user on same post was **not** fixed. Doing this (voting more than once on same post) is still **against the rules** and should be dealt with, even if it's being cleaned up. I'm not sure what makes you want to let users vote several times on same post, and also your last sentence is totally unclear and weird. What on Earth politics got anything to do with a voting bug???????

Comment: You could make this argument about all bad behavior on the site though: spam, defacing posts, serial voting, etc. All of it is cleaned up and undone but we still punish the people who do these things. I don't see a benefit in allowing bad actors to keep acting badly.