# "Serial voting reversed" on my profile - upvote removed

Tags: support, reputation, serial-voting

[Note: I'm **not** concerned with actual reputation loss but rather intrigued by this use case]

[image]

Got the above. I believe it means that someone was on a **up**voting spree, that was detected and reversed.

While I've heard about serial **down**voting when multiple questions and/or answers got downvoted by the same user in a short period of time, the opposite is news to me.

What would be a likely ***motive*** for such action when no sock puppets are involved?

Comment: +1 serial voting would have been strange.

Comment: @animuson - It was my first then I got confused about the exact wording looking at [clarification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/379854/213957).

Comment: Closed it as dupe.

Comment: In the event that this wasn't due to the duplicated vote script, sometimes users just *really* liked one of your answers, and wanted to go and upvote the rest of them to show their thanks. Those kind of votes are frequently invalidated. You'll likely never see a voting reversal to reverse only one vote cast in this manner, though.

Comment: @Spevacus Having a single -10 could happen with any number of reversed upvotes, if the affected user had hit the reputation cap on the original voting day as a result of votes which weren't reversed and the total of the reversed votes put the user just below the rep cap. It's not something that's going to happen all that often, but it's definitely possible, and almost certainly has happened.